# Delete entire row when a column reaches 0?

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have this database table "userDeck", with three columns: idUser, idCard, amount. Amount is a counter that keeps track of how many cards the user has added of a specific card. Right now I'm using this query:

```
$query1 = "UPDATE userDeck SET amount=amount-$amount WHERE idCard=$idCard"; 
$result2 = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());
```

when the user wants to delete cards he/she added.

This works just fine except it continues below 0 if you delete more cards than you have listed. I want it to remove the row when amount reaches 0.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the statement:

```
DELETE FROM userDeck WHERE idCard=$idCard and amount = 0
```

immediately after the update.

```
$query1 = "DELETE FROM userDeck WHERE idCard=$idCard and amount = 0";
$result2 = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Thanks! Used this except I added amount <= 0 to prevent the value to go below 0 and it seems to work correctly!

Answer (score 0):

Two ways

1. Use an "application control" at php level and don't give user ability for delete that card
2. Use a where condition to exclude those records that had an `amount = 0`

Comment: A trigger would not do because it would not be able to affect the very same table if was acting for.

Comment: @ShlomiNoach now about circular reference but this is an update-->delete sequence ... Is still "valid" this concept?

Comment: Circular reference will not be detected at `CREATE` time, but will fail on runtime.

Comment: @ShlomiNoach: is nice to learn new things. Thank you for this explaination.

Comment: @DonCallisto There's a nasty trick which can be used if your table is `MyISAM`: you can wrap it up with a `MERGE` table, then ask the trigger to work on that `MERGE1 table. For a complex usage, see [Auto caching tables](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/auto-caching-tables)

Comment: @arxanas : trigger isn't a valid solution in that case, so please remove you +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$query1 = "UPDATE userDeck SET amount=amount-$amount WHERE idCard=$idCard"; 
$result2 = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());
```

You could then run this after:

```
$query_del = "DELETE FROM userDeck WHERE idCard=$idCard AND amount = 0"; 
mysql_query($query_del) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM userDeck WHERE amount<=0
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the solution offered by Gordon, also consider changing the type of `amount` to `UNSIGNED` (Assuming it is an INTEGER type), along with a [strict sql_mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_all_tables).

This will raise an error should you attempt to set the value to a negative one.